# Cucumber Java Convert Data Table to Specific Type

Tags: java, cucumber

I want to use a data table in my feature file and have the contents converted to a single specific type in the step definition. For Example I would like to be able to convert the following data table into a single instance of the User class.

```
 Given the user is
    | firstname  | lastname  | nationality |
    | Roberto    | Lo Giacco | Italian     |
```

The User class:

```
class User {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Nationality nationality;
//getters / setters / etc
}
```

Step Definition:

```
 @Given("^the user is$")
 public void the_user_is(User user) {
     this.user = user;
 }
```

However when I run this I get the following error:

> cucumber.runtime.CucumberException:
>   cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Not a Map or List type: class example.User

The documentation suggests that it is possible to convert a data table to a single object.

[Cucumber Transpose API Docs](https://cucumber.github.io/api/cucumber/jvm/javadoc/cucumber/api/Transpose.html)

However from inspecting the code it looks like it will always return a list. This code snippet is from cucumber/runtime/table/TableConverter.convert(DataTable dataTable, Type type, boolean transposed) :

```
Type itemType = listItemType(type);
if (itemType == null) {
    throw new CucumberException("Not a Map or List type: " + type);
}
```

I know it works for a list:

```
 @Given("^the user is$")
 public void the_user_is(List<User> user) {
     this.user = user.get(0);
 }
```

but in my real world step (rather than this simplified example) there is only ever one object that needs created and I want to avoid using a list and then taking the first item.

Comment: Why not pass the data table to your step method?

Comment: The point is to not have to have the DataTable or a List in the step definition, but instead be given directly the single instance of the object defined in the feature file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an old issue regarding this problem in the *cucumber-jvm* repo on GitHub. It was recently labeled as a bug and is expected to be solved in release 2.1.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/741

Comment: This bug is specific to the @Transpose annotation but it should be possible whether I'm using a transposed data table or a regular data table. I've commented on the bug to try to clarify this. Accepting the answer as I believe it will be solved as part of this bug